# When edit a elementor template showing error "Session expired"

Tags: wordpress, elementor

When i going to edit a elementor template then showing error message:

**Session expired**

*Please log in again. The login page will open in a new tab. After logging in you can close it and return to this page.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2gE2.png)

Answer (score 0):

same problem with me, since yesterday. I have tried many ways in settings but nothing works. Atlast i found this was cookie problem in my browser. I loggedIn with private tab (Guestmode) and tried and it worked for me